# Binding the style of the control to a Viewmodel property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I am trying to create a banner with different states and colors to show messages to the user, showing a `Border` with a specific style and a `Label` with an style bases in the `Border` style and using `DataTrigger`. I have created each custom styles for each state in my `App.xaml` and I am trying to change the state based on a property of my ViewModel.

The problem is that the style doesn't change every time I change the property, but nevertheless if I modify some of the XAML during debugging, the style is refreshed correctly.

Maybe I am missing a `NotifyPropertyChanged` somewhere?

Visual example:

[image]

This is My code:

`App.xaml` with my defined styles and my custom converter

```xml
<Application.Resources>

    <local:StyleConverter x:Key="StyleConverter" />

    <Style x:Key="Banner" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="Banner_Info" TargetType="{x:Type Border}" BasedOn="{StaticResource Banner}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#e3f7fc" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#8ed9f6" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="Banner_Error" TargetType="{x:Type Border}" BasedOn="{StaticResource Banner}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ffecec" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#f5aca6" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="Banner_Success" TargetType="{x:Type Border}" BasedOn="{StaticResource Banner}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#e9ffd9" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#a6ca8a" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="Banner_Text" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BorderBrush.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Border}}}" Value="#8ed9f6">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#31708F" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BorderBrush.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Border}}}" Value="#f5aca6">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#B10009" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BorderBrush.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Border}}}" Value="#a6ca8a">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#529214" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Application.Resources>
```

`Styleconverter.cs`

```cs
public class StyleConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        if (targetType != typeof (Style)) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException ("The target must be a Style");
        }

        var styleProperty = parameter as string;
        if (value == null || styleProperty == null) {
            return null;
        }

        string styleValue = value.GetType ()
            .GetProperty (styleProperty)
            .GetValue (value, null)
            .ToString ();
        if (styleValue == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Style newStyle = (Style) Application.Current.TryFindResource (styleValue);
        return newStyle;
    }

    public object ConvertBack (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }
}
```

`Banner.cs`

```cs
public class Banner : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private string _Message;
    public string Message {
        get => _Message;
        private set {
            _Message = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged (null);
        }
    }

    private string _Style = "Banner_Success";
    public string Style {
        get => _Style;
        private set {
            _Style = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged (null);
        }
    }

    public Banner SetSuccess (string message) {
        Style = "Banner_Success";
        Message = message;

        return this;
    }

    public Banner SetInfo (string message) {
        Style = "Banner_Info";
        Message = message;

        return this;
    }

    public Banner SetError (string message) {
        Style = "Banner_Error";
        Message = message;

        return this;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged (string PropertyName) {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs (PropertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

`Mainwindow.xml`

```xml
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">

        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{Binding ., Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource StyleConverter}, ConverterParameter=BannerStyle}">
                <Label Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource Banner_Text}" Content="{Binding BannerMessage}" />
            </Border>
        </Grid>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Padding="10" Margin="10" Content="BLUE" Command="{Binding CmdChangeColor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CommandParameter="blue" />
            <Button Padding="10" Margin="10" Content="RED" Command="{Binding CmdChangeColor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CommandParameter="red" />
            <Button Padding="10" Margin="10" Content="GREEN" Command="{Binding CmdChangeColor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CommandParameter="green" />
        </StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

`MainViewModel.cs`

```cs
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    
    public Banner Banner { get; } = new Banner ();
    public string BannerStyle => Banner.Style;
    public string BannerMessage => Banner.Message;

    public RelayCommand CmdChangeColor { get; }

    public MainViewModel () {
        Banner.SetSuccess ("This is the initial message");

        CmdChangeColor = new RelayCommand (param => ChangeColor (param.ToString ()));
    }

    public void ChangeColor (string color) {
        switch (color) {
            case "blue":
                Banner.SetInfo ("INFO!! This should be a banner with blue background");
                break;

            case "red":
                Banner.SetError ("ERROR!! This should be a banner with red background");
                break;

            case "green":
                Banner.SetSuccess ("SUCCESS!! This should be a banner with green background");
                break;
        }

        RaisePropertyChanged (null);
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged (string PropertyName) {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs (PropertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Why `RaisePropertyChanged(null)` and not `RaisePropertyChanged("Style")`?

Comment: Because, with `RaisePropertyChanged(null)` you notify the changed for all properties, instead only one.

Comment: Do you have any supporting doc for that? Can't find it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventargs?view=net-5.0)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventargs.propertyname?view=net-5.0#remarks

Comment: My mind is blown. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bind to *property* which has notifications, instead of entire view model (`{Binding .}`). This way also simplifies converter (no more reflection)

```
<Border Style="{Binding Path=Banner.Style, Converter={StaticResource StyleConverter}">
```

```
public class StyleConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        if (targetType != typeof (Style)) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException ("The target must be a Style");
        }

        string styleValue = value?.ToString();
        if (styleValue == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Style newStyle = (Style) Application.Current.TryFindResource (styleValue);
        return newStyle;
    }

    public object ConvertBack (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }
}
```